Cursor jumps to end when editing SwiftUI TextField on Binding
I have an editable list defined as:
@Binding var ingredients: [Ingredient]

...

NavigationView {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach($ingredients) { $ingredient in
                if ingredientsEditMode == .active {
                    TextField("Name", text: $ingredient.displayText)
                } else {
                    Text(ingredient.displayText)
                }
            }
            .onDelete { _ in
                print("delete")
            }
        }
    }
    .toolbar {
        EditButton()
    }
    .environment(\.editMode, $ingredientsEditMode)
    .navigationTitle("Edit Ingredients")
}

ingredients is defined in the parent view:
@Binding var recipe: Recipe

...

let ingredientBinding = Binding($recipe.ingredients)


When editing any individual text field, editing content in the middle of the string causes the cursor to jump to the end.
I suspect this is because the state is changing and the whole page is re-rendering (similar SO question).
How can I prevent this?

ingredientBinding Is ver unorthodox

Was able to solve this!
I updated my loop to include id: \.id, like this:
ForEach($ingredients, id: \.id) { $ingredient in
    TextField("Edit ingredient", text: $ingredient.displayText)
}

